# Qual é o plural de ‘hostel’?

Tags: ortografia, estrangeirismos

‘Hostel’ é um estrangeirismo do inglês, e vejo frequentemente o plural como ‘hostels’.

Mas se ‘hotel’ tem como plural ‘hotéis’, por que não se diz e se escreve ‘hostéis’?

Comment: Talvez porque a forma plural foi emprestada junto com a singular?

Comment: No Brasil é comum chamar *hostel* de *albergue*.

Comment: Em Portugal, chamamos a um *hostel*, "pousada". Neste caso então, o plural seria "pousadas".

Answer (score 7):

O corrector ortográfico e sintáctico [FLiP](http://www.flip.pt/FLiP-On-line/Corrector-ortografico-e-sintactico.aspx) não reconhece a palavra "hostel" como portuguesa, embora o dicionário Priberam a [liste](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/hostel) como inglesa e dê exemplos da sua utilização em textos de blogs portugueses. Nele se confirma que o plural é "hostels". Também [não consta do VOLP](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario).

Embora esta palavra já seja usada no singular e se ouça no plural a forma inglesa "hostels", ainda não faz parte do léxico português. Poder-se-á vir a dizer "hostéis", mas, neste momento, **esta forma não soa bem**,  pelo menos em Portugal. Por outro lado, o Brasil julgo ser em geral mais rápido a aportuguesar os estrangeirismos, pelo que a acontecer é natural que seja desse lado do Atlântico.

Comment: Já agora *hostéis* soa muito mal mesmo.

Comment: @JorgeB. soal mal devido ao **s** antes do **t** e por ter novamente outro no fim? Ou porque relembra [**hostia** em Espanhol](http://www.bomespanhol.com.br/girias/paises/espanha/hostia-s)? É interessante, pois _[hotéis](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/hot%C3%A9is)_ é o plural de _hotel_.

Comment: @Armfoot sim é mesmo por isso. **Hostéis** parece "hotéis" dito de forma errada, parece uma pronuncia de algum lugar. E também fica parecido com **hostis** que é o plural de [Hostil](http://www.dicio.com.br/hostil/). Depois de tanto dizer essa palavra agora só me parece que estou a espirrar "hostéis" :P

Comment: Também dá a ideia de Espanhol dá...

Comment: Acho que não é nada comum no português termos duas consoantes seguidas de duas vogais...

Comment: `Acho que não é nada comum no português termos duas consoantes seguidas de duas vogais...` discordo completamente com isto, @JorgeB. - pa**stéi**s, a**ctua**l, embre**nhai**s, aca**rtou**, la**mpei**ro, etc. (Com o resto, concordo.)

Comment: @ANeves por isso é que eu disse "acho" estava só no achismo, agora já confirmaste que é ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ontem, 6 de Maio de 2020, primeira comemoração do dia mundial da língua portuguesa, ouviram-se, de novo, nos telejornais, «pérolas» de elevado quilate. Por exemplo, ouvi José Alberto Carvalho, na TVI, a pluralizar a palavra inglesa «hostel» à maneira portuguesa: «hostéis». Depois, ouvi André Ventura a usar a mesmíssima «palavra». Já ouvi isto mais algumas vezes. Papel - papéis... Logo, «hostel» - «hostéis»!... Sou só eu a achar tal prática uma imbecilidade? Ainda por cima, é escusadíssimo o uso, tão vulgarizado, de «hostel», na língua portuguesa. Não faltam, no nosso idioma, vocábulos para traduzir o inglês «hostel»: pensão, residencial, pousada, estalagem, albergue, albergaria, hospedaria e, talvez, mais algumas. Enfim... A língua portuguesa sempre em «evolução»...

Comment: O Hostel é uma versão globalizada e [gentrificada](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentrifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o) das anteriores modalidades hoteleiras.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Exchange professor Pedro Silva!

Comment: Podemos juntar um reparo, o "tuk-tuk" foi a moda que seguio o "hostel" em Lisboa. Ora, não precisavamos de importar o nome asiático "tuk-tuk", chamavamo-lhe "papa-reformas bus"; ou "tu-kamone tu-kamone", ou "ape50 mais qualquer coisinha". Agora "tuk-tuk" é que não, passamos no Martim Moniz e mais parece Nova Deli.